# How to overcome an import error while importing the tables package in python?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytables

I have been trying to open the tables package in anaconda prompt, but I keep running into the following error:

```py
In [1]: import tables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0a99ad28a088> in <module>
----> 1 import tables

~\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\tables\__init__.py in <module>
     43
     44 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
---> 45 from .utilsextension import get_hdf5_version as _get_hdf5_version
     46
     47

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing utilsextension: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling "tables", but I still repeatedly get the above error every time I try to load the package. Can anyone suggest a way to overcome this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show us the `ls ~\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\tables`?

Comment: seems like you have uninstall `tables`

Comment: Are you installing with conda package manager? Have you verified `tables` is part of your anaconda environment? To do so: open a command window (use **Anaconda Prompt** on Start menu), and enter this command `conda list pytables`.